# Landscape Deployment slow download causes timeout

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, landscape

I've been troubleshooting deployment timeouts all day and I finally narrowed it down

I'm getting about average 100kb/s download speed from the cloud images repository. I've verified that it is not my connection as speedtest.net shows 60Mb/s down. I tried downloading an image to my desktop using a browser and 150MB file took almost 20 minutes.

Does anyone know whats going on or how to increase the 2700 second timeout on Landscape deployments?

Comment: I started using wily and liberty and downloads are much faster.